# How to get Kinect working with Cinder on a Mac

Tags: xcode, macos, kinect, cinder

I've been racking my brain trying to figure this out and I'm stumped. I'm currently following this tutorial:

http://examples.oreilly.com/0636920022657/Hack%2023%20Create%20Hand%20Tracking%20Trails%20Using%20Cinder/SimpleHandTracking.txt

However, step 7 says to add the Kinect.cpp file and the Cinder-Kinect repo that they mention https://github.com/cinder/Cinder-Kinect does not have this file.

Also, open to new ways of handling the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up using this blog which I found extremely helpful: http://blog.nelga.com/setup-microsoft-kinect-on-mac-os-x-10-9-mavericks/

Along with this cinder block: https://github.com/wieden-kennedy/Cinder-OpenNI

Answer (score 0):

[Kinect Cinder SDK](https://github.com/BanTheRewind/Cinder-MsKinect/tree/master/src) contains Kinect.cpp file and Kinect.h file. Most Probably, they are talking about these files.

Note : Above sdk is for kinect v1.

Comment: So I tried https://github.com/wieden-kennedy/Cinder-KCB (the one you posted is no longer supported) and there are additional header files in KinectCommonBridgeLib.h which can't be found.

Comment: Is [this](https://github.com/wieden-kennedy/Cinder-KCB/tree/master/lib) what you are looking for?

Comment: No, because that header files requires additional windows header files. :/